# Setting local preference in BGP

Tags: routing, bgp

I am trying to set the local preference for this configuration

[image]

To make a route from R1 to R4 via R3. That's how i configure R3

```
R3#conf term
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
R3(config)#route-ma
R3(config)#route-map
% Incomplete command.

R3(config)#route-map bakatele permit 12
R3(config-route-map)#set local-preference 213
R3(config-route-map)#exit
R3(config)#exit
R3#
*Mar  1 05:28:42.506: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
R3#conf ter
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
R3(config)#router bgp 230
R3(config-router)#neighbor 10.0.34.2 route-map bakatele in
R3(config-router)#exit
R3(config)#exit
R3#conf term
```

after that i obtain that the local preference is set:

```
R3#show ip bgp
BGP table version is 3, local router ID is 3.3.3.3
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete

   Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
* i192.168.11.0     10.0.12.1                0    100      0 100 i
*  192.168.41.0     10.0.35.2                              0 500 400 i
*>                  10.0.34.2                0    213      0 400 i
* i                 10.0.24.2                0    100      0 400 i
*  192.168.51.0     10.0.35.2                0             0 500 i
*>                  10.0.34.2                     213      0 400 500 i
* i                 10.0.24.2                0    100      0 400 500 i
```

But after checking trace-route command nothing seems to be changed, because before and after setting the preference, the trace-route looks exactly the same:

```
R1#traceroute 192.168.41.1 source 192.168.11.1

Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 192.168.41.1

  1 10.0.12.2 12 msec 12 msec 24 msec
  2 10.0.24.2 60 msec 28 msec 36 msec
```

Router1:

```
R1#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1325 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
no ip domain lookup
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 192.168.11.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.12.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
router bgp 100
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.11.0
 neighbor 10.0.12.2 remote-as 230
 neighbor 10.0.12.2 update-source FastEthernet0/0
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
control-plane
!
banner motd ^C 2018-12-13 16:00:45 gMEZtcIf5EbHO75rQ3yVJYEW7chKAfPI ^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
end
```

Router2:

```
R2#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1780 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
no ip domain lookup
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.12.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.24.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/1
 ip address 10.0.23.1 255.255.255.252
 clock rate 2000000
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 2.2.2.2 0.0.0.0 area 1
 network 10.0.23.0 0.0.0.3 area 1
!
router bgp 230
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 remote-as 230
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 next-hop-self
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 route-map bakatele in
 neighbor 10.0.12.1 remote-as 100
 neighbor 10.0.12.1 update-source FastEthernet0/0
 neighbor 10.0.24.2 remote-as 400
 neighbor 10.0.24.2 update-source FastEthernet0/1
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
control-plane
!
banner motd ^C 2018-12-13 16:00:45 ischKmPlaiSYFJOgOutRt7N5Ub3fCG4y ^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Router3:

```
R3#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1882 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R3
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.34.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.35.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/1
 ip address 10.0.23.2 255.255.255.252
 clock rate 2000000
!
router ospf 1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 3.3.3.3 0.0.0.0 area 1
 network 10.0.23.0 0.0.0.3 area 1
!
router bgp 230
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 remote-as 230
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 next-hop-self
 neighbor 10.0.34.2 remote-as 400
 neighbor 10.0.34.2 update-source FastEthernet0/0
 neighbor 10.0.34.2 route-map bakatele in
 neighbor 10.0.35.2 remote-as 500
 neighbor 10.0.35.2 update-source FastEthernet0/1
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
route-map bakatele permit 12
 set local-preference 213
!
control-plane
!
banner motd ^C 2018-12-13 16:00:45 geN8EtGYiItCbAXA7DWB1qGLpc3bc268 ^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Router4:

```
R4#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1596 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R4
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 4.4.4.4 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 192.168.41.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.34.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.24.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 10.0.45.1 255.255.255.252
 speed 100
 full-duplex
!
router bgp 400
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.41.0
 neighbor 10.0.24.1 remote-as 230
 neighbor 10.0.24.1 update-source FastEthernet0/1
 neighbor 10.0.34.1 remote-as 230
 neighbor 10.0.34.1 update-source FastEthernet0/0
 neighbor 10.0.45.2 remote-as 500
 neighbor 10.0.45.2 update-source FastEthernet1/0
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
control-plane
!
banner motd ^C 2018-12-13 16:00:45 KmdbwQMyWblS6qmtj5RKxbgkR4WXDKMf ^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Router5:

```
R5#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1421 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R5
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip auth-proxy max-nodata-conns 3
ip admission max-nodata-conns 3
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
archive
 log config
  hidekeys
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 5.5.5.5 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback1
 ip address 192.168.51.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.0.45.2 255.255.255.252
 speed 100
 full-duplex
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.35.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
router bgp 500
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.51.0
 neighbor 10.0.35.1 remote-as 230
 neighbor 10.0.35.1 update-source FastEthernet0/1
 neighbor 10.0.45.1 remote-as 400
 neighbor 10.0.45.1 update-source FastEthernet0/0
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
control-plane
!
banner motd ^C 2018-12-13 16:00:45 abUopoUFfHVQgJ7DfCr6nU01jAhTGRg4 ^C
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Can you tell me where do I make the mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue in this case is that R2 is making the decision, not r3. You need to take the route maps off of r3, and apply the same one to set local pref On r2 inbound from r3. That is course assuming that you change the distance of ibgp. Otherwise you would be limited to a few options, such as, blocking the route inbound on r2.